# Getting Else Syntax Error in Binary to Decimal Translation Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Currently trying to write a code for my CS class, translating an 8 digit binary number to decimal. The code needs to exclude all digits not 0,1, as well as incorrect character length. The error is focusing on the else statement. My book doesn't cover my error, and my internet searches have the same result.

```
if re.match("01", binary):

#check for correct entry length
    if len(binary == 8):
        print(int(binary, 2)
    else:
         print("The entry must be 8 digits")
   #^syntax error
else:
    print("Only numbers 1 and 0 may be used")
```

Comment: What is the actual error/problem you are having? A possible problem lies in len(binary == 8), which should result in an error. You likely want len(binary) == 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with the following

```
    if re.match("01", binary):

#check for correct entry length
    if len(binary )== 8:
        print(int(binary, 2))
    else:
         print("The entry must be 8 digits")
   #^syntax error
else:
    print("Only numbers 1 and 0 may be used")
```

Comment: Thank you, I've got it corrected now. Seeing both of my errors definitely has me thinking a little differently about correcting an error.

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error -> `if len(binary == 8)`

this should be `if len(binary) == 8`

Comment: Thank you. I actually discovered I had this issue the second I fixed my parentheses issue.